# How to negate a regex for pandas replace

Tags: python, regex, pandas

In pandas I can search and replace all fields that contain the word fish, for example, using `df.replace(r'.*fish.*', 'foo', regex = True)`.

> But how do I search and replace all fields that don't contain the
>   word fish?

That is in my example replace all fields that don't contain the word fish with the word 'foo'.

For example, say the dataframe is

```
applefish pear
water     afishfarm
```

I would like this to be transformed to

```
applefish foo
foo       afishfarm
```

Comment: What does your dataframe look like and what is your expected output?

Comment: Duplicate of [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use negative look ahead (`?!`) assertion; `^(?!.*fish).*$` will firstly assert the pattern doesn't contain the word `fish` and then match every thing till the end of string and replace it with `foo`:

- `^` denotes the beginning of string, combined with `(?!.*fish)`, it asserts at BOS that there is no pattern like `.*fish` in the string;
- If the assertion succeeds, it matches everything till the end of string `.*$`, and replace it with `foo`; If the assertion fails, the pattern doesn't match, nothing would happen;

so:

```
df.replace(r'^(?!.*fish).*$', 'foo', regex=True)
#           0           1
#0  applefish         foo
#1        foo   afishfarm
```

---

If the string can contain multiple words:

```
df
#                0          1
#0  applefish pear       pear
#1           water  afishfarm
```

You can use word boundary `\b` to replace `^` and word characters `\w` to replace `.`:

```
df.replace(r'\b(?!.*fish)\w+', 'foo', regex=True)
#               0           1
#0  applefish foo         foo
#1            foo   afishfarm
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain the `^` and `$`  please. I assume they mark the start and end of the field but why are they needed? Also, why do we need the brackets? The close bracket is also before the final `.*` which is surprising.

Comment: Sure. Updating with some explanations.

Comment: Also, why don't you need the `r'` ?

Comment: Wow, I thought it wasn't doable but you sure showed otherwise. Nice.

Comment: The `$` is not necessary, but you would need `^` to assert at the beginning of string, otherwise, `farm` will get replaced because the cursor moves to the middle of string and the assertion succeeds. The parenthesis is part of the syntax for regex look around.

Comment: However this assumes each word is in a separate column. I was not working under this assumption.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks for the comment. Updated with an option to handle multiple-word strings.

Comment: I un-marked this as a duplicate because this inline `.*text` way is faster because it doesn't enter into an assertion on each character as opposed to `(?:(?!text).)*` ...  `Regex1:   ^(?!.*fish).*$
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   100  /  100     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    0.43 s,   426.74 ms,   426741 µs


Regex2:   ^(?:(?!fish).)*$
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   100  /  100     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    0.53 s,   525.90 ms,   525899 µs`

Comment: @sln Thanks for checking out.

Answer (score 6):

You can use apply with str.contains

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.replace(x[~x.str.contains('fish')], 'foo'))
```

You get

```
    0           1
0   applefish   foo
1   foo         afishfarm
```

Note: I wouldn't even recommend this as Psidom's solution is way more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it helps someone with a similar Problem:
If you want to filter a DF with a negate regex use it in this way:

```
new_DF = df.loc[**~**df['columnName'].str.match(r'your regex here')]
```

If you have None Values there than don't forget:

```
... match(r'your regex here', na=True)
```

otherwise you get an ERROR